# Is there a workaround that I can use so that I can test the build type when using CMake in combination with Visual Studio and multiple configurations?

Tags: cmake

I would like to work with 'Debug', 'Release', 'Debug_Unicode' and 'Release_Unicode'
I have been able to use the `DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS` variable so that the 'Debug Unicode' configuration correctly gets used as debug

This is what I tried to do in the *CmakeLists.txt* file:

```
    target_link_libraries(tests 
                                optimized   ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/foo.lib
                                debug       ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/foo.lib
                         )
```

Clearly CMake is able to make a choice between debug and release at this point, as it has to choose the 'optimized' or 'debug' library.
However, `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is an empty string.

The best that I have been able to come up with is to work with a separate solution file for each of the configurations,
passing in `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` myself:

```
cmake -G Visual Studio 11 2012 Win64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug_Unicode C:\foo
```

Comment: What you have done so far is, in fact, the correct way to proceed.

Comment: Normally for `target_link_libraries` you don't need to specify the full library path for targets you build within the project. Writing `target_link_libraries(tests foo)` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

As Antonio was mentioning

```
target_link_libraries(tests foo)
```

or just

```
add_dependencies(tests foo)
```

would be sufficient to link the correct library from the same configuration.

If you want to do more advanced stuff, take a look at the [generator expressions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html). They are configuration sensitive incl. in Visual Studio's multi-configuration environment and they would work also for the `target_link_libraries()` command.

So your example would look like:

```
target_link_libraries(tests ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/$<CONFIG>/foo.lib)
```

I have used generator expression e.g. in custom commands that need to be aware of the output path of my DLL (if `foo` would be generating an MSTest DLL):

```
 add_test(
     NAME RunFooTest
     WORKING_DIRECTORY $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:foo>
     COMMAND vstest.console.exe /InIsolation /Platform:x86 $<TARGET_FILE:$foo>
 )
```

And - just because you mentioned different solutions - you can use CMake to build a certain configuration from the command line. This would in your case look like e.g.

```
cmake --build C:\foo --target ALL_BUILD --config Debug_Unicode
```